# Cloudstack development environment

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins, jetty, apache-cloudstack

I'm trying to set up a development environment in eclipse for Cloudstack.
Until now I have been able to setup everything and run the mvn commands with jetty:run so I can see it in my localhost:8080/client.

So far so good.

What I want to achieve is to develop some plugins easily. The problem is that as far as I do something, I need to re-deploy the whole project to see the changes. I have been looking some tutorials on how the jetty server can see those changes and show them in Cloudstack right after I pressed the "save" button in eclipse.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just recompile your specific plugin and cloud-client.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm developing a UI plugin. Recompiling the UI project would take less time, which is way better but not perfect.

Comment: For UI you just need to recompile cloud-client module.
Alternatively you can modify the "packaged/compiled" sources within client/target/generated-webapp/


rm -r client/target/generated-webapp/*.gz
cp -rf ui/* client/target/generated-webapp/

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CLOUDSTACK/UI+Plugin+Tutorial